# ManyToMany bean models does not have an Id value

Tags: playframework-2.0, many-to-many, ebean

I have 2 models with `ManyToMany` relationship. Tried this and it works:

```
@Entity
public class EmployeeProfile extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<Expertise> expertises;
}

@Entity
public class Expertise extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;
}
```

Yes. In this model I don't have `List<EmployeeProfile>` on `Expertise` side yet it works.

This doesn't work, even when `expertises` is empty:

```
@Entity
public class EmployeeProfile extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<Expertise> expertises;
}

@Entity
public class Expertise extends Model {

    @Id
    public UUID id;
    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;
}
```

It shows `ManyToMany bean models.Expertise@344eba6f does not have an Id value.`

This works only if `expertises` is empty:

```
@Entity
public class EmployeeProfile extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public List<Expertise> expertises;
}

@Entity
public class Expertise extends Model {

    @Id
    public UUID id;
    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;
}
```

On the third example, when `expertises` isn't empty it shows duplication error. Apparently when I tried to save an `EmployeeProfile` object and the object has object in `expertises`, it will try to save the `Expertise` object even though I only want to save the `EmployeeProfile_Expertise` relationship, not the `Expertise` itself.

Any idea to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Apparently when I tried to save `EmployeeProfile`, I already have 4 objects in `expertises`. Removing the empty objects (the one without valid ID) solve the problem.